# SQL: calculating the change in total for each day using date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have the following table:

```
Date        |  Store  |  Total
2018-05-02     ABC       56.98
2018-05-02     DEF       60.34 
2018-05-02     XYZ       46.50
2018-05-03     ABC       80.43
2018-05-03     DEF       70.09
2018-05-03     XYZ       95.98
2018-05-04     ABC       43.52
2018-05-04     DEF       90.23
2018-05-04     XYZ       88.12
```

I am trying to create a query that will output the above table with an additional column called PrevTotal that for each store, will have its Total on the previous day. I also want to disregard all entries which have the first date (2018-05-02) in the output table (since you can't get the previous total for the first day). 
E.g. the output should be:

```
Date        |   Code   |   Total   |   PrevTotal 
2018-05-03      ABC        80.43       56.98
2018-05-03      DEF        70.09       60.34
2018-05-03      XYZ        95.98       46.50
2018-05-04      ABC        43.52       80.43
2018-05-04      DEF        90.23       60.34
2018-05-04      XYZ        88.12       95.98
```

I am not sure how I can go about creating a query that will help me do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using? window functions might be your solution: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/

Comment: I think `2018-05-04      DEF        90.23       60.34` should be `2018-05-04      DEF        90.23       70.09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me.

```
SELECT s2.*, s1.Total 
FROM Stores s1
LEFT JOIN Stores s2 on s1.Store = s2.Store
     AND DATEDIFF(day, s2.Date, s1.Date) = -1

WHERE s2.Total IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY s1.Date, s1.Store
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use 2nd max id like but null data you can not avoid better you just ignore data while fetching/displaying :

```
SELECT tbl2.Date, tbl2.Store, tbl2.total, 
(select total from test_table tbl1 where tbl1.Store = tbl2.Store and tbl1.id < tbl2.id) as prev_Total 
FROM `test_table` tbl2
```

Result :

```
Date       |   Store  |  total | prev_Total |
--------------------------------------------
2019-03-21 |   ABC    |  56.98 | NULL       |
--------------------------------------------
2019-03-21 |   DEF    |  60.34 | NULL       |
--------------------------------------------
2019-03-21 |   XYZ    |  46.50 | NULL       |
--------------------------------------------
2019-03-21 |   ABC    |  80.43 | 56.98      |
--------------------------------------------
2019-03-21 |   DEF    |  70.09 | 60.34      |
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of MySQL, the code can be made more readable by using [windowing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) function

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKAbtGWF4paTxkbzA8ieST/0

```
with a as 
(
  select 
      date, store, total, 
      lag(total) over(partition by store
                      order by date) as prev_total
  from t
)
select *
from a
where prev_total is not null
order by date, store
```

Output:

```
| date                | store | total | prev_total |
| ------------------- | ----- | ----- | ---------- |
| 2018-05-03 00:00:00 | ABC   | 80.43 | 56.98      |
| 2018-05-03 00:00:00 | DEF   | 70.09 | 60.34      |
| 2018-05-03 00:00:00 | XYZ   | 95.98 | 46.5       |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:00 | ABC   | 43.52 | 80.43      |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:00 | DEF   | 90.23 | 70.09      |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:00 | XYZ   | 88.12 | 95.98      |
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the previous total will not always be from the date - 1 day, but maybe there would be gaps between the days, so you must find the previous date for each store:

```
select t.*, tt.total prevtotal
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on 
  tt.store = t.store 
  and 
  tt.date = (
    select max(date) from tablename where store = t.store and date < t.date
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tRuLrd9b1j23EZkqopxyUv/0).
Results:

```
| date       | store | total | prevtotal |
| ---------- | ----- | ----- | --------- |
| 2018-05-03 | ABC   | 80.43 | 56.98     |
| 2018-05-03 | DEF   | 70.09 | 60.34     |
| 2018-05-03 | XYZ   | 95.98 | 46.5      |
| 2018-05-04 | ABC   | 43.52 | 80.43     |
| 2018-05-04 | DEF   | 90.23 | 70.09     |
| 2018-05-04 | XYZ   | 88.12 | 95.98     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are consecutive, a `join` does exactly what you want:

```
select t.*, tprev.total as prev_total
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.code = t.code and tprev.date = t.date - interval 1 day;
```

`lag()` is also possibility in MySQL 8+.  With the right indexes, I don't know which would be faster.